# Blank slide in Bootstrap 3 between every image slide

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've used Bootstrap carousel in my webpage but there is a problem in the slides.  The first image slides with content, second is blank, then third image slides, then third image there is blank page slide.

My code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/site/img/daa.jpg"  >
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/site/img/2.jpg" >
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="/site/img/grad.jpg" >
        </div>
    </div> 
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

No margins, no padding, no .left or .right , and finally no spaces in the code..
What could the problem be?

Comment: can you please provide fiddle where we can see issue as you mentioned sass so it will be great to have fiddle with your issue.(https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues im edited your code [Look at new updated](https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/pookzwy1/1/) and now you can understand **Bootstrap Carousel Plugin**

```
 The Carousel plugin is a component for cycling through elements, like a carousel (slideshow).
```

Learn more about it [W3SCHOOL](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="http://s32.postimg.org/osirordf9/2_black_wallpaper_pattern_preview.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="http://s32.postimg.org/osirordf9/2_black_wallpaper_pattern_preview.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="http://s32.postimg.org/osirordf9/2_black_wallpaper_pattern_preview.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest. I've used fiddle and tested my carousel, it worked fine there,
so after more effort, I detected the problem. It was because I have css file with

```
.next,.prev{
display: none !important;  
}
```

but I don't understand  deeply why it causes blank slide, not only white sides in my slides!

thanks again